# Read XML Attribute from URL

Tags: c#, xml

Guys it can read all elements but it can't read Attribute. This is link: https://www.korayspor.com/grisport.xml

I need read to attributes of Categories. It is "Kategori" in Turkish. Like "Kategori **no="8988"**>

This code doesn't work :

```
case XmlNodeType.Attribute: 
   xmlSet.WriteAttributeString(reader.Name, reader.Value);
   break;
```

The whole code :

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("https://www.korayspor.com/grisport.xml");
        XmlTextWriter xmlSet = new XmlTextWriter("sdfsdf", UTF8Encoding.UTF8);
        xmlSet.WriteStartDocument();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    xmlSet.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.Text: 
                    xmlSet.WriteValue(reader.Value);
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.CDATA: 
                    xmlSet.WriteCData(reader.Value);
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.EndElement: 
                    xmlSet.WriteEndElement();
                    break;

                **case XmlNodeType.Attribute: 
                    xmlSet.WriteAttributeString(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                    break;**

            }
        }
        xmlSet.WriteEndDocument();
        xmlSet.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I accessed your XML and used Visual Studio to generate the classes using the Paste XML as Classes in the Edit -> Paste Special menu.

Added the rest of the code inside the XmlStuff class to get the object hydrated for you:

```
namespace SEQuestion
{
    public class XmlStuff
    {
        public Urunler GetXml()
        {
            var uri = $"https://www.korayspor.com/grisport.xml";
            var serializer =
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(Urunler));

            using var reader = XmlReader.Create(uri);
            var newExport = (Urunler)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            return newExport;
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Kategori")]
    public class Kategori
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "no")] public string No { get; set; }
        [XmlText] public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Stok")]
    public class Stok
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "label")] public string Label { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Barkod")] public string Barkod { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Ozellik")] public string Ozellik { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Stoklar")]
    public class Stoklar
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Stok")] public List<Stok> Stok { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "urun")]
    public class Urun
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UrunID")] public string UrunID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UrunAdi")] public string UrunAdi { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Kod")] public string Kod { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fiyat")] public string Fiyat { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ListFiyat")]
        public string ListFiyat { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "KdvOran")] public string KdvOran { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Marka")] public string Marka { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Aciklama")] public string Aciklama { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ImageName")]
        public string ImageName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Kategori")] public Kategori Kategori { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Renk")] public string Renk { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Stoklar")] public Stoklar Stoklar { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Urunler")]
    public class Urunler
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "urun")] public List<Urun> Urun { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsd { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is my interview Project. I will use this.

Comment: @Baran Polar good to know. Make sure to accept this or jdweng answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "https://www.korayspor.com/grisport.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XElement urun = doc.Descendants(ns + "urun").Where(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "Kategori").Attribute("no") == "8988").FirstOrDefault();
            string text = (string)urun.Element(ns + "Kategori");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I could not tell sorry. I create new XML file and  i will write informations I recieved from link. Only I can't get attributes.

Comment: XML serialization like Bruno suggested is very slow.   The code is already slow because of the size and time to download.  Using Anonymous solution can use a lot of memory.  The best solution is to create a class with just properties you need and then fill the class from xml linq.  The class reduces the amount of memory (and speed) and xml linq is good at flattening the output and only parsing the data you need.  Serialization you need a class for each level of hierarchy in the xml file while xml linq you do not need the hierarchy.